# Enabling and disabling a selectOneMenu via selectBooleanCheckbox

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, jsf-1.2

I have (according to some other answers I found here) the following:

```
<a4j:outputPanel id="qualSelectorWrapper" ajaxRendered="true">
    <h:selectOneMenu id="qualSelector" value="#{xmlCreator.qualFilename}" disabled="#{!xmlCreator.qualFileEnabled}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{si:toSelectFileList(appController.directoryContents)}"/> 
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</a4j:outputPanel>
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{xmlCreator.qualFileEnabled}">
    <a4j:support event="onclick" reRender="qualSelector"/>
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

unfortunatly, clicking the checkbox does absolutely nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To be sure, you're using RichFaces 3.x, not 4.x? You've posted 3.x syntax which won't work in 4.x. Regardless, it would always be helpful if you mention the exact JSF and component library impl/version in every JSF related question.

Comment: Oh sorry, I totally forgot that. Faces 1.2, richfaces 3.3.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing

```
<a4j:support event="onclick" reRender="qualSelector"/>
```

to

```
<a4j:support event="onclick" ajaxSingle="true" reRender="qualSelector"/>
```

seems to do the trick.

Found via [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566695/jsf-command-button-enable-disable-based-on-jsf-check-box-using-java-script).